# React Router DOM using separate files for routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Basically I want to seperate the public and private routes in two different files for simplicity, however it seems like the first component put inside the Switch in App.js is being hit and not the other, thus if and routes are being hit in the second component in Switch it would render a blank page as the route is being looked from the first component in the Switch.

App.js

```
<Switch>
      <UnAuthenticatedRoutes />
      <AuthenticatedRoutes />
 </Switch>
```

UnAuthenticatedRoutes.jsx

```
 <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage}/>
 <Route path="/about" component={AboutPage}/>
```

AuthenticatedRoutes.jsx

```
 <ProtectedRoute path="/profile" component={ProfilePage}/>
 <ProtectedRoute path="/documents" component={DocumentsPage}/>
```

So the problem is if I put "/about" in the URL it hits to the first component (UnAuthenticatedRoutes) and renders the page correctly, however, if I try to go to "/profile" (after being authenticated) it renders nothing because it is looking up the "/profile" in the UnAuthenticatedRoutes file (since it comes before the AuthenticatedRoutes in the App.js). I was expecting it to look it up in the AuthenticatedRoutes after it fails to find it in UnAuthenticatedRoutes which is not the case. How can I overcome this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "because it is looking up the "/profile" in the UnAuthenticatedRoutes file" this seems unclear to me, I do not see a profile route in the unAuthenticatedRoutes file ? You should edit the 3 files to show them in total.

Comment: I mean that it is looking into the first component in the App.js to find the matching path as "/profile" which it can't find as it does not exist in that file. So I expect it to look into the second component (AuthenticatedRoutes) when it fails to find it in the first component. @LukeCelitan